# Sync data between 2 systems

Tags: php, e-commerce, synchronization

We have a E-commerce system and back end Order management system. From order management system we need to sync many information like order status and item status and shipment status and many others. Right now we have taken a API approach where in E-commerce system exposes a API and we use these APIs to push data to them. Now data has become huge and number of API calls are becoming huge. Is there any alternative and effective method which we can use in this scenario.

We are using REST API's

Answer (score 2):

If you have proper and secure API then you can use it to sync data between two system.

You just need to make API call using **cron job**. Set a cron job with period of 1 min ( or 5 min, 10 min, ..) as per your requirement so your orders and/or other informations are periodically send to other system wia API call. By cron job, you'll decrease the load of current system and also sync data.

To set cron job, you also need to maintain date-time, so once some records are send to other system, they are not included in next call.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe how the API is being called but if you're calling the API 'live' i.e. every time a record is modified, you could put the modified records in a queue instead and send multiple records per API call at a time (a cron job that runs every 10 minutes for example could process your queue).

Sending multiple records per API call via a queue will significantly reduce the # of total calls and the associated overhead.
Additionally, it provides a simple way to handle sync errors (if a sync fails just reinsert the failed records into the queue).